# Weird UI glitches?

Tags: bug, user-interface

I've been experiencing a lot of UI glitches today (see attached image).

Is there any reason why I'm seeing these glitches?

[image]
[image]

I'm using the most recent version of Chrome on MacOS

Comment: Any answers? It happens constantly and it makes doing anything really annoying.

Comment: Usually with a bug report, one should mention the platform/browser it was encountered upon. (It's far from obvious to me what those might be.)

Comment: @rschwieb edited

Comment: If you right click on the page and Inspect, and highlight the Console tab, are there any weird errors?  As I do that now, it's totally clean.  A browser error that might explain this would show up there.

Comment: @rschwieb There's one error: failed to load resource: err_blocked_by_server sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js:1

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I'm also getting weird-ui-glitches:1599 as an error on a "proper" refresh. Looking at the jQuery, it looks like there might be an issue getting a parent node but I'm not sure. I've also gotten weird-ui-glitches:30 which is a stylesheet import. Maybe there's a certs issue?

Comment: I"m on 79.0.3945.130 Chrome on macos and am not currently seeing a problem.

Comment: @DonThousand: I am experiencing exactly the same things. All that changed recently was an update to Chrome on Windows 10. I wonder if a Chrome change has caused this intermittent problem. I see it across all stack exchanges. I am  running Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise, V 1809.

Comment: @Moo Do you use ghostery?

Comment: @DonThousand: Yes, I do, plus Adblock Plus, Flash Blocker, Disable HTML Autoplay and several others and I keep them up to date.

Comment: @Moo Try disabling ghostery, or trusting the site, and reloading

Comment: Just tried it on MSE and it seems to resolve the issue. Left some other SE sites with Ghostery enabled and it is failing like above on those. Maybe the combination of the recent update of Chrome with something in Ghostery (as I do not recall it being updated for a bit now).

Comment: @DonThousand: By the way, sometimes I even see the MathJax not rendering as another weird display issue.

Comment: @Moo Yea same, I have the exact same situation.

Comment: Looks like whatever the bug was it is gone now. I haven't experienced it at all today.

Comment: @CameronWilliams It isn't completely gone for me. It shows up once in a while. Not sure what is going on.